# header('location: ./') redirects to which page in php

Tags: php

I am learning how to use the facebook-login on my website and I found this code online which logs us in and after a successful login it is sending it to header('location: ./'). Now I want to know where it redirects to. There is only one index page in my folder and the code is as follows:

```
    <?php
// Include FB config file && User class
require_once 'fbConfig.php';
require_once 'User.php';

if(isset($accessToken)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }else{
        // Put short-lived access token in session
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

        // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

        // Set default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }

    // Redirect the user back to the same page if url has "code" parameter in query string
    if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        header('Location: ./');
    }

    // Getting user facebook profile info
    try {
        $profileRequest = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,gender');
        $fbUserProfile = $profileRequest->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // Redirect user back to app login page
        header("Location: ./");
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    // Initialize User class
    $user = new User();

    // Insert or update user data to the database
    $fbUserData = array(
        'oauth_provider'=> 'facebook',
        'user_id'   => $fbUserProfile['id'],
        'first_name'    => $fbUserProfile['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $fbUserProfile['last_name'],
        'email'         => $fbUserProfile['email'],
        'gender'        => $fbUserProfile['gender']
    );
    $userData = $user->checkUser($fbUserData);

    // Put user data into session
    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;

    // Get logout url
    $logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl($accessToken, $redirectURL.'logout.php');

    // Render facebook profile data
    if(!empty($userData)){
        $output  = '<h1>Facebook Profile Details </h1>';
        $output .= '<img src="'.$userData['picture'].'">';
        $output .= '<br/>Facebook ID : ' . $userData['user_id'];
        $output .= '<br/>Name : ' . $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'];
        $output .= '<br/>Email : ' . $userData['email'];
        $output .= '<br/>Gender : ' . $userData['gender'];


        $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="'.$logoutURL.'">Facebook</a>'; 
    }else{
        $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Some problem occurred, please try again.</h3>';
    }

}else{
    // Get login url
    $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);

    // Render facebook login button
    $output = '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($loginURL).'"><img src="images/fblogin-btn.png"></a>';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login with Facebook using PHP by CodexWorld</title>
<style type="text/css">
    h1{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#999999;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Display login button / Facebook profile information -->
    <div><?php echo $output; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying this code to implement the possibility to login using facebook on my website and after a successful login it should redirect to the index page of my project.

Comment: it will redirect you current directory . if you have index file it will load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header('location: ./')` don't use this instead use `header('location:/')`

Answer (score 0):

header('location: ./') will redirect you to the directory folder.

Word of advice, do not use header('location: ./') but rather ('location:/').